# show attributed text in JSQ Textmessage Chat screen

Tags: ios, iphone, nsattributedstring, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

i am working on chatting app and using jsqmessageviewcontroller. but i am facing issue in text messages. my app functionalty is that. i have to show some words in different colors in JSQ cell.NSString is working but  JSQ Textmessage not supporting NSAttributedString.. if there is any way to use attributed string in jsq . please refer me to any helpfull link. ..here is type of colord attribued string   [image]

Comment: This might be interesting for you : https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/pull/1059

Comment: thanks bro.. This link solved the problem